# How can I make a snapshot image of a web page in php?

Tags: php, image, snapshot

I am using php and I want to take a snapshot of my web page using php. Something similar to this

http://www.moneycontrol.com/gd/mail_indices.php

How can i do that?

Comment: This isn't a snapshot of a webpage, but a generated image. This means it's not generated from HTML/CSS, but programatically inside a PHP script using e.g. [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Comment: yes that's what exactly i want....just got a bit confused at the time of asking this question.But this image was created from a webpage actually.How can i create an image that contains all the html tags etc in php???

Comment: Taking "snapshots" of html pages using PHP is not something easily achieved, to say the least. Yes, php has support (using GD library) for creating/handling images, but that's the easiest part. the hard thing is rendering a page - like browsers do - and taking it's snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest and surest way in PHP to create images is to look at the [GD Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). They have tons of functions to help you create your image easily.

Should you need a font that is available in Windows Font but not in PHP font, you can use this tool to convert it: http://www.wedwick.com/wftopf.exe

Answer (score 2):

To take Snapshots of a website, and not as proposed generate an image with text in it, you can use either

http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/ for snapshots using IE's rendering engine or
http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/ for Webkit (Safari/Chrome) snapshots

I strongly recommend the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Imagemagick](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/dynamic-images-imagemagick).

Answer (score 1):

Theres is a comprehensive summary of image creation option in Php [here](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/image_creation_with_php_formats.html). The other option not already mentioned is [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/cairo-php/).