# is it possible to generate a screenshot of an HTML section?

Tags: php, html, image, screenshot

I am looking for a way to dynamically generate a screenshot from an HTML `<section>`. Is this possible? If so, then how?

Comment: Means you want to create image of html page?

Comment: You can refer this link for creating image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745467/programatically-create-image-from-web-page-or-a-single-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702986/generate-image-from-html-with-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480793/how-can-i-make-a-snapshot-image-of-a-web-page-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do it is by using PhantomJS.

See the 2 links and mix and match!

// rasterize.js
http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/taking-website-screenshots-using-phantomjs/

// stuff to hack into it
[How to render part of a page with PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs)

Good luck mate!